# How to get all lines manually drawn on chart

Tags: charts, pine-script

I need to find all horizontal lines manually drawn (via Toolbar) on a chart. So that I can find intersections of candle-stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done in Pine.
There no way to access manually drawn objects.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway to add multiple horizontal lines as required? While running a script, I need to see if I should draw a line? So I want a script that draw lines whenever its required like a mouse click etc?

Comment: Pine does not allow for interactions with a mouse click. You can however draw horizontal lines in a Pine script. You'd need to program it to draw that line at the price point you want. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish though.

Comment: Can you please help me getting the first candle on the visible area of the chart? Like while I am moving left-right, it should give me an index of the current bar from right?

Comment: This also cannot be done. There's nothing in Pine that allows to interact with only the visible part of the chart. A Pine script always runs from the first historical bar to the current bar.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to access all previously drawn lines. In the October 2021 update, they added support for it. [Release Notes Update October 2021](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/Release_notes.html?highlight=notes#october-2021)

Just type `line.all`

It is possible to get all objects of these data types `label.all`, `line.all`, `box.all` and `table.all`. But it is **not** possible to get all **hline**, so you will have to use **line** instead.

This is a code example where all previously drawn lines are coloured white, but the last line is coloured green.[image: last line green]

```
//@version=5
indicator("line access", overlay=true)

for [index, value] in line.all
    line.set_color(value, color.white)
    
line.new(bar_index - 4, close[4], bar_index, close, color=color.green, width = 2)
```

Comment: line.all only gives lines drawn in the script.